# Removed Windows 7 and installed Ubuntu Server 12.04, but Windows Boot Manager still appears

Tags: 12.04, boot, server, grub2, windows-7

I removed Windows 7 and installed Ubuntu Server 12.04, but when the computer starts a black screen for Windows Boot Manager appears that looks like this:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  Status: 0xc0000225

  Info: The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.
```

I want to remove it and I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [*boot-repair*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair),it would be the best option to repair your bootloader.

Comment: I'm trying to use it but I can't when I type this command " sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update" appear this error: 'sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found'

Comment: try this command `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`.